# Find the perimeter of a triangle.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute-angled triangle in which $D,E,F$ are points on $BC,CA,AB$ respectively such that $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC,AE=EC,CF$ is bisects angle C internally. Suppose $CF$ meets $AD$ and $DE$ in $M,N$ respectively . If $FM=2,MN=1,NC=3$, find the perimeter of triangle $ABC$.
It is the problem. Somebody help me.I can't proceed it.

[image]

Comment: According to given it may be an equilateral triangle. Probably it must be equilateral, try proving this.

Comment: For the OP: many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's) best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Comment: OP, do you have any questions concerning my answer? If so, please ask away, and I'll be happy to explain. However, if you are satisfied with the answer, I'd appreciate it if you indicate your approval by clicking on the check mark or on the upvote next to my answer (or on both). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is an elaboration of [Mick's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1975645/37058). Mick deserves most of the credit.

1. $E$ bisects $AC$ and $N$ bisects $CF$. Therefore $ED || AB$. Therefore $\angle EDC = \angle B$.
2. $E$ bisects the hypotenuse of the right-triangle $\Delta ADC$. Hence $ED = EC$. Hence $\angle EDC = \angle C$. So $\angle B = \angle C$. So $AB = AC$.
3. $AD$ is a median of $\Delta ABC$. The medians of a triangle divide one another by a ratio $2:1$. $M$ divides $CF$ by a ratio $2:1$. Therefore, $CF$ is a median of $\Delta ABC$.
4. Since $CF$ is both a median and an angle bisector, $AC = CB$. So $\Delta ABC$ is an equilateral.
5. $\Delta AFC$ is a $30-60-90$ triangle. Therefore $\frac{6}{AC} = \frac{CF}{AC} = \cos(30^\circ) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Hence $AC = 4\sqrt{3}$. Therefore $\Delta ABC$'s perimeter equals $12\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $FM=2,MN=1,NC=3$, (1) will DE // BA?; and (2) will F be the midpoint of AB? (3) ...